# openCL Kernel to calculate Pi is not correct value

Tags: c, for-loop, kernel, opencl, pi

Good day,

I have an openCL kernel that is using the Leibniz formula to calculate pi. Currently my issue is that the value I get back isn't pi, but instead just 4.

```
__kernel void calculatePi(int numIterations, __global float *outputPi,
                          __local float* local_result, int numWorkers)
{
    __private const uint gid = get_global_id(0);
    __private const uint lid = get_local_id(0);
    __private const uint offset = numIterations*gid*2; 
    __private float sum = 0.0f;

    // Have the first worker initialize local_result
    if (gid == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
        {
            local_result[i] = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    // Have all workers wait until this is completed
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    // Have each worker calculate their portion of pi
    // This is a private value
    for (int i=0; i<numIterations; i++) 
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum += 1 / (1 + 2*i + offset);
        }
        else
        {
            sum -= 1 / (1 + 2*i + offset);
        }
    }

    // Have each worker move their value to the appropriate
    // local_result slot so that the first worker can see it
    // when reducing next
    local_result[gid] = sum;    

    // Make sure all workers complete this task before continuing
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    // Have the first worker add up all of the other worker's values
    // to get the final value
    if (lid == 0)
    {
        outputPi[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++)
        {
            outputPi[0] += local_result[i]; 
        }

        outputPi[0] *= 4;
    }    
}
```

I've steered all of my inputs to my output to verify that they are what I expect. numIterations is 16 and numWorkers is also 16.

When sum is calculated then for the first worker, I would expect the sum to be
1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + 1/13 - 1/15 + 1/17 - 1/19 + 1/21 - 1/23 + 1/25 - 1/27 + 1/29 - 1/31

Using this calculator for the first 16 times, I expect the result to be around 3.2 : https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/19546118/

If I modify my last bit of code to be this so that I can look at a worker's calculated value of "sum":

```
    // Have the first worker add up all of the other worker's values
    // to get the final value
    if (lid == 0)
    {
        outputPi[0] = sum * 4;
    }
```

Then the value returned for the first worker is 4 instead of the expected 3.2

Modifying to any other number except lid == 0, all other workers are reporting their sum as 0. So my question is why is that the calculated value? Am I doing something wrong with my sum variable? This should be a private variable and the for loop should be sequential from my understanding for each worker but numerous loops are executed in parallel based on the number of workers.

Here's a link to my github that has the kernel and main code uploaded.

https://github.com/TreverWagenhals/TreverWagenhals/tree/master/School/Heterogeneous%20Computing/Lab2

Thanks

Comment: I would expect  offset = numIterations / (gid*2); or am i wrong?

Comment: No I don't think so. The next term for the next worker (gid==1) should start at 1/33 (I showed the first 16 terms above). So, the offset is 16*1*2 = 32. For the first loop of the for-loop, the calculation would then be + 1/(1 +2(0) + 32) = + 1/33, which is what is expected. Just for sanity, I tried what you said too and it results in a floating point exception (16/(15*2) = 16/30, which is not an integer anymore, so that makes sense that it isn't correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are performing integral divisions in your code, should be floats:

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
{
   sum += 1. / (1 + 2*i + offset); // notice the 1.
}
else
{
   sum -= 1. / (1 + 2*i + offset);
}
```